# How to call dbHash with RunCommand using MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, mongo-go

Using the MongoDB Driver for Go I would like to execute the `dbHash` command using `RunCommand`. I am confused with the "Key" and "Value" pairs that I should use for `RunCommand`. One thing to note: I would like to pass in a specific collection name to hash, denoted as `collection` in this example. For example this is what I have now: `db.RunCommand(context.Background(), bson.D{primitive.E{Key: "dbHash: 1", Value: fmt.Sprintf("collections: %s", collection}})`. Please let me know how I should implement this.

References:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dbHash/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`bson.D`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#D) represents a document, it is an ordered collection of properties represented by [`bson.E`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#E), which is a simple struct holding the property name and value:

```
type E struct {
    Key   string
    Value interface{}
}
```

Each field of the command must be an element inside the `bson.D` document. The `collections` field in the command must be an array, which in your case will contain a single element. In Go, you may use a slice for such an array.

So let's create the command document:

```
cmd := bson.D{
    bson.E{Key: "dbHash", Value: 1},
    bson.E{Key: "collections", Value: []string{collection}},
}
```

Note: you may omit the `bson.E` types from the elements, it is inferred from the type of `bson.D`:

```
cmd := bson.D{
    {Key: "dbHash", Value: 1},
    {Key: "collections", Value: []string{collection}},
}
```

Let's execute this command, capturing the result document in a [`bson.M`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#M) map:

```
var result bson.M
if err := db.RunCommand(context.Background(), cmd).Decode(&result); err != nil {
    log.Printf("RunCommand failed: %v", err)
}
fmt.Println(result)
```